# Is it not possible to have an array based Queue with generics ?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

This is an array based Queue , for `int` :

```
/**
 * Array based
 * @author X220
 *
 */

public class MyQueue {

    private int[] _data;
    private int MAX_SIZE;
    private int front = -1;
    private int back = 0;
    private int elementsCount = 0;

    public void printQueue()
    {
        int j = this.front + 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this._data.length && i < elementsCount)
        {
            System.out.println("At location " + j % MAX_SIZE + " element :" + this._data[j % MAX_SIZE]);
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public MyQueue(int _size)
    {
        MAX_SIZE = _size > 0 ? _size : 10;
        this._data = new int[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    public boolean IsEmpty()
    {
        return this.elementsCount == 0;     
    }

    public boolean IsFull()
    {
        return this.elementsCount == MAX_SIZE;
    }

    public void Push(int pushMe) throws QueueIsFullException
    {
        if (IsFull())
        {
            throw new QueueIsFullException("Queue is full");
        }
        this.elementsCount++;
        _data[back++ % MAX_SIZE] = pushMe;
    }

    public int Pop() throws QueueIsEmptyException 
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            throw new QueueIsEmptyException("Queue is full");
        }
        elementsCount--;
        return _data[++front % MAX_SIZE];
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            MyQueue q1 = new MyQueue(15);
            q1.Push(1);
            q1.Push(2);
            q1.Push(3);
            q1.Push(4);
            q1.Push(5);
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Push(6);
            q1.Pop();
            q1.Push(7);
            q1.Push(8);
            q1.Push(9);
            q1.Push(10);
            q1.Push(11);
            q1.Push(12);


//          q1.Push(1);
//          q1.Push(2);
//          q1.Push(3);
//          q1.Push(4);
//          q1.Push(5);
//          q1.Push(7);
//          q1.Push(8);
//          q1.Push(9);
//          q1.Push(10);
//          q1.Push(11);
//          q1.Push(12);
//          q1.Push(40);
//          q1.Push(50);
            q1.printQueue();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class QueueIsFullException extends Exception 
    {
          public QueueIsFullException(String message){
             super(message);
          }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class QueueIsEmptyException extends Exception 
    {
          public QueueIsEmptyException(String message){
             super(message);
          }

    }

}
```

I wanted to use generics so I changed the `int` to `T` but then I got for this :

```
public class MyQueue <T>{

    private T[] _data;
    private int MAX_SIZE;
    private int front = -1;
    private int back = 0;
    private int elementsCount = 0;

    public void printQueue()
    {
        int j = this.front + 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this._data.length && i < elementsCount)
        {
            System.out.println("At location " + j % MAX_SIZE + " element :" + this._data[j % MAX_SIZE]);
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public MyQueue(int _size)
    {
        MAX_SIZE = _size > 0 ? _size : 10;
        this._data = new T[MAX_SIZE];
    }

....


}
```

That :

> - Cannot create a generic array of T

And from the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) I see that I can't use generics with arrays .

Does this mean that there is no work around for a generics Queue based on array ? Must I switch to some other data structure ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21664946/1057429

Comment: Why not just use [`java.util.ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)?

Comment: I like to write my own data structures , sometimes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is not with your MyQueue class, I think you misunderstand the way Java handles generics. Generic types exist only at compile time, after that they are simply erased from the byte code and at runtime only real Java types exist behind the scenes.

This is why you cannot *instantiate* a generic type, because at runtime this parameterized type simply doesn't exist.

What you can do is to provide a real class (extending T) as a parameter in your MyQueue class an instantiate this class type, since this is a first-class Java type.

Here is a very similar StackOverflow question and a solution:
[Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

It is also recommended to read the Java reference about generics, like the answer for you original question is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects

Comment: I switched to ArrayList . Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

No there is a work around for this the ugly cast, change your array generic creation to:

```
        this._data = (T[])new Object[MAX_SIZE];
```

Due to the implementation of Java generics, you can't have code like this:

```
        this._data = new T[MAX_SIZE];
```

Have a look at this [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The method I prefer is using

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] arr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz,length);
```

where `clazz` is the `Class<T>` object corresponding to the generic type. Note that the cast is unchecked, but `Array.newInstance` ensures you that you won't be able to insert invalid types into your array.

To me this is the best solution because :

- you handle the type consistency to the `Array` class by passing a `Class<T>` instance which will be used to cast all the objects inserted in the array. This is thus type-safe without needing you to do anything.
- this is relatively small and self-contained, it won't force you to manually cast objects over and over everytime you use the array. This would be the case if you were using an `Object[]` under the hood.

Comment: Some answers say that this solution might cause `ClassCastException` , from here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java`

Comment: I've always used it with no problems. The cast is unchecked if my memory is correct, so it cannot fail. This method returns an array which component type is guaranteed to be of type `T`, and you can then cast it to get the assignment to compile. It is just a convenience for writing `T[]` instead of `Object[]`, this cast won't check anything