# Java sorting dynamically defined arraylist of objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I want to sort this

```
LG Electronics  1.jpg   
Apple   2.JPG   
Apple   3.JPG
```

As

```
Apple   2.JPG   
Apple   3.JPG
LG Electronics  1.jpg
```

Here is my code
//rows is 2d

```
ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    com.drew.metadata.Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(images[i]);
    for (com.drew.metadata.Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
        for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
            //System.out.println(tag.toString());
            if(tag.toString().contains("[Exif IFD0] Make")){
                rows.add(new String[]{tag.getDescription(),images[i].toString()});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented `Collections.sort(rows);` but nothing works for me. I even tried

```
Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
    return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
    }
    });
```

But it also doesn't works for me. I got this error that  no suitable method found for sort(arraylist

Comment: rows is a List<String[]>. So its elements are String[]. So, to compare them, you need a Comparator<String[]>.

Comment: Can you help me doing that I'm really stuck implementing everything. Seems nothing works for me..

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664875/java-generics-array-of-the-generic-type it mentions an item from Josh Bloch's book Effective Java... where he clearly mentions never mix Generics with Array. That's first thing... In general Josh suggests that try to keep the things simple in your programming and then solutions will just come simple as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against using a model such as `ArrayList<String[]> rows` in your case because it really doesn't tell much about what the list is holding -- and it makes implementing the comparison clunky.

Instead, you could model the metadata as a Java class:

```
public class Metadata {

  private final String description;
  private final String imageName;

  public Metadata(String description, String imageName) {
    this.description = description;
    this.imageName = imageName;
  }
  public String getDescription() {return description;}
  public String getImageName() {return imageName;}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return description + " " + imageName;
  }
}
```

Now, you can have a `List<Metadata> rows = new ArrayList<>();` which you populate inside the loop only changing this part:

```
rows.add(new String[]{tag.getDescription(),images[i].toString()});
```

into this

```
rows.add(new Metadata(tag.getDescription(), images[i].toString());
```

And finally, you can sort with a proper `Comparator` using

```
Collections.sort(rows, Comparator
                        .comparing(Metadata::getDescription)
                        .thenComparing(Metadata::getImageName));
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you think this answers your question, you can also choose to accept the answer.

Comment: Now what if I want to get the original values after sorting like:

Apple   2.JPG   

Apple   3.JPG

LG Electronics  1.jpg 


Now when i print `rows` after sorting all i get is output like`
sorting.Data@387f0054`
How can I can get specific values like `imageName`

Comment: I modified the `Metadata` class to include a `toString()` implementation which should take care of the problem (and you can change as you wish). I think there is a checkbox you can tick in the UI somewhere for accepting the answer.

Comment: done brother that was really helpful... I was stuck here but i think grateful to you